# R keras package Error: Python module tensorflow.contrib.keras.python.keras was not found

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I have `keras` installed with `devtools` from GitHub in R and TensorFlow installed in Python.

However when I run an example Keras command like:

```
model <- keras_model_sequential()
```

I get the following:

> Error: Python module tensorflow.contrib.keras.python.keras was not
>   found.
>
> ```
> Detected Python configuration:
>
> python:         C:\Python35\python.exe
> libpython:      C:/Python35/python35.dll
> pythonhome:     C:\Python35
> version:        3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:27:37) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
> Architecture:   64bit
> numpy:          C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy
> numpy_version:  1.13.0
> tensorflow:     C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow
>
> python versions found: 
>  C:\Python35\python.exe
>  C:\Python27\\python.exe
>  C:\Python35\\python.exe
>  C:\Python36\\python.exe
> ```

Comment: You appear to have many python versions installed. Is R perhaps linked to the wrong version (where tensorflow is installed)?

Comment: Yes, this looks like a wrong python version issue.

Comment: But it's hitting 3.5 which is the right one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Restart rstudio, load keras and tensorflow libraries, and type `use_condaenv("r-tensorflow")`. That fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks; I don't use Anaconda in this machine though

Comment: The latest version of Keras in R has fixed this. Update the keras package and type `install_keras()` .

Comment: congrats you're my damn hero

Comment: @Yoav24 I thought they fixed it but I am glad it helped you.

Comment: It's been 4 or 5 years since I asked so I'll have to assume this is the answer (I'm not on Windows so I can't really test it) and will mark this as the solution based on the comments.

Comment: Installing anything in Python seems horrendously difficult compared to R. There are no standards. Like, installing tensorflow with the package manager pip does not work. You need something called anaconda/miniconda, define a separate environment, or even run everything in a Docker? This is ridiculous guys. We need to rewrite keras in native R.

Answer (score 5):

First, you can install the R tensorflow package from [here](https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow/blob/master/README.md).

Then, you can just install the latest tensorflow version, using install_tensorflow function, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45348964/4610379).

After that, just install and update R-keras library. It should use the last version of TensorFlow now, and this could potentially solve your problem. Also, make sure you install the tensorflow version that matches your Python version.

Answer (score 5):

I faced a similar problem and below steps helped to overcome the issue.

1. Install  TensorFlow and Keras from rstudio github.

- `devtools::install_github("rstudio/tensorflow")`
- `devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")`

2. Execute the below

- `tensorflow::install_tensorflow()`
- `tensorflow::tf_config()`

Comment: And then, `library("keras")` should follow.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem. 
The issue was solved by updating the *tensorflow* module from 1.0.1 to 1.2.1

Comment: I didn't use H2O clusters. I have independent Keras and tensorflow installations. I upgraded the  tensorflow package outside of R via the _pip_ command.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with a conda installation on a Mac (so using `install_keras(method = 'conda', conda = '/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda')`, which created a virtual environment called `r-reticulate` under `~/.conda/envs`. Then when I tried to instantiate a model just like you do, I was getting an error 'Error: Python module tensorflow.python.keras was not found.'

For me what resolved it is after loading `library(keras)` execute `use_condaenv("r-reticulate", required = TRUE)` and then everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, I tried all above given solution but didn't work.
It worked for me when I created env using, both in spyder and R

```
conda create -n keras-tf tensorflow keras
```

In windows

```
library(keras)
library(tensorflow)
use_condaenv("keras-tf", required = T)
```

In Python

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

Answer (score 0):

Some times your env and system don't have any problems, it is just the way how you configure Tensorflow and Keras that cause these errors to be raised.

below is how I fixed mine:

```
{install.packages("tensorflow")
install.packages("keras")
tensorflow::tf_config()
mytf <- tf$compat$v1}
```

the configuration results shows the following output:

```
2021-12-09 11:43:39.007746: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2021-12-09 11:43:39.007931: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
TensorFlow v2.6.2 ()
Python v3.7 (C:/Users/myName/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python.exe)
```

then type:

```
install_keras()
```

after that you can test:

```
mnist <- keras::dataset_mnist() ; mnist
```

this will give you an output like:

```
$train
$train$x
, , 1

         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16]
    [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0    
....
$train$y
   [1] 5 0 4 1 9 2 1 3 1 4 3 5 3 6 1 7 2 8 6 9 4 0 9 1 1 2 4 3 2 7 3 8 6 9 0 5 6 0 7 6 1 8 7 9 3
  [46] 9 8 5 9 3 3 0 7 4 9 8 0 9 4 1 4 4 6 0 4 5 6 1 0 0 1 7 1 6 3 0 2 1 1 7 9 0 2 6 7 8 3 9 0 4
  [91] 6 7 4 6 8 0 7 8 3 1 5 7 1 7 1 1 6 3 0 2 9 3 1 1 0 4 9 2 0 0 2 0 2 7 1 8 6 4 1 6 3 4 5 9 1
 [136] 3 3 8 5 4 7 7 4 2 8 5 8 6 7 3 4 6 1 9 9 6 0 3 7 2 8 2 9 4 4 6 4 9 7 0 9 2 9 5 1 5 9 1 2 3
 [181] 2 3 5 9 1 7 6 2 8 2 2 5 0 7 4 9 7 8 3 2 1 1 8 3 6 1 0 3 1 0 0 1 7 2 7 3 0 4 6 5 2 6 4 7 1
 [226] 8 9 9 3 0 7 1 0 2 0 3 5 4 6 5 8 6 3 7 5 8 0 9 1 0 3 1 2 2 3 3 6 4 7 5 0 6 2 7 9 8 5 9 2 1
 [271] 1 4 4 5 6 4 1 2 5 3 9 3 9 0 5 9 6 5 7 4 1 3 4 0 4 8 0 4 3 6 8 7 6 0 9 7 5 7 2 1 1 6 8 9 4
 [316] 1 5 2 2 9 0 3 9 6 7 2 0 3 5 4 3 6 5 8 9 5 4 7 4 2 7 3 4 8 9 1 9 2 8 7 9 1 8 7 4 1 3 1 1 0
 [361] 2 3 9 4 9 2 1 6 8 4 7 7 4 4 9 2 5 7 2 4 4 2 1 9 7 2 8 7 6 9 2 2 3 8 1 6 5 1 1 0 2 6 4 5 8
 [406] 3 1 5 1 9 2 7 4 4 4 8 1 5 8 9 5 6 7 9 9 3 7 0 9 0 6 6 2 3 9 0 7 5 4 8 0 9 4 1 2 8 7 1 2 6
 [451] 1 0 3 0 1 1 8 2 0 3 9 4 0 5 0 6 1 7 7 8 1 9 2 0 5 1 2 2 7 3 5 4 9 7 1 8 3 9 6 0 3 1 1 2 6
 [496] 3 5 7 6 8 3 9 5 8 5 7 6 1 1 3 1 7 5 5 5 2 5 8 7 0 9 7 7 5 0 9 0 0 8 9 2 4 8 1 6 1 6 5 1 8
 [541] 3 4 0 5 5 8 3 6 2 3 9 2 1 1 5 2 1 3 2 8 7 3 7 2 4 6 9 7 2 4 2 8 1 1 3 8 4 0 6 5 9 3 0 9 2
 [586] 4 7 1 2 9 4 2 6 1 8 9 0 6 6 7 9 9 8 0 1 4 4 6 7 1 5 7 0 3 5 8 4 7 1 2 5 9 5 6 7 5 9 8 8 3
 [631] 6 9 7 0 7 5 7 1 1 0 7 9 2 3 7 3 2 4 1 6 2 7 5 5 7 4 0 2 6 3 6 4 0 4 2 6 0 0 0 0 3 1 6 2 2
 [676] 3 1 4 1 5 4 6 4 7 2 8 7 9 2 0 5 1 4 2 8 3 2 4 1 5 4 6 0 7 9 8 4 9 8 0 1 1 0 2 2 3 2 4 4 5
 [721] 8 6 5 7 7 8 8 9 7 4 7 3 2 0 8 6 8 6 1 6 8 9 4 0 9 0 4 1 5 4 7 5 3 7 4 9 8 5 8 6 3 8 6 9 9
....
[ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 9000 entries ]
```