# Error : Python module tensorflow.python.keras was not found

Tags: r

I want to convert some numeric values into category.
I am using 'keras' package for image classification.

When I am using to_categorical(trainy), getting "Error: Python module tensorflow.python.keras was not found."

I have taken trainy <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1) and convert it into categorical values.

```
library(keras)
library(tensorflow)
trainy <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1)
trainLabels <- to_categorical(trainy)
```

The values in that vector should be converted into categorical values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R keras package Error: Python module tensorflow.contrib.keras.python.keras was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44611325/r-keras-package-error-python-module-tensorflow-contrib-keras-python-keras-was-n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works perfectly in my machine.

Please check that you used the `install_keras()` command to install keras and/or Tensorflow for R in your machine.

So your code would be like this:

```
library(keras)
library(tensorflow)

install_keras() # or install_tensorflow() depending on what you want

trainy <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1)
trainLabels <- to_categorical(trainy)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Eror: Error 1 occurred creating conda environment r-tensorflow . Creating r-tensorflow conda environment for TensorFlow installation...
Solving environment: ...working... failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: -

Comment: Opened new session and rerun the code, now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
conda create -n tf tensorflow
conda activate tf
```

Or, to install the current release of GPU TensorFlow on Linux or Windows:

```
conda create -n tf-gpu tensorflow-gpu
conda activate tf-gpu
```

Install GPU TensorFlow on Windows using Anaconda prompt with above command.Then re install the tensorflow package in RStudio, load the library (tensorflow). Now run the command

```
trainLabels <- to_categorical(trainy)
```

This worked for me.