# Error in virtualenv_install for tensorflow in R

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train a model using keras library in RStudio.

```
library(keras)
N <- 100
x <- runif(N, -2, 3)
# Build a Gompertz function with some noise
a <- 10 # ceiling parameter
b <- 0 # horizontal shift parameter
c <- 2 # growth rate parameter
y <- a*exp(-exp(b - c*x)) + rnorm(N, mean=0, sd= a/10)
plot(x,y)
# format data in a way model.fit() would like it
x <- as.matrix(x)
y <- as.matrix(y)
# sequence along x for later prediction
xnew <- as.matrix(seq(from=min(x), to=max(x), length.out=1000))
# Build and compile simple model
model <- keras_model_sequential() |>
layer_dense(units=32, activation="relu", input_shape=1) |>
layer_dense(units=16, activation = "relu") |>
layer_dense(units=1, activation="linear")
```

at this point I got an error

> ```
> Error: Python module tensorflow.keras was not found.
>
> Detected Python configuration:
> ```

I found a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56736849/error-python-module-tensorflow-python-keras-was-not-found) and tried to

```
library(keras)
library(tensorflow)
install_tensorflow()
install_keras()
```

But I got this error:

> Error in virtualenv_install(envname = envname, packages = packages,
> ignore_installed = pip_ignore_installed,  :    '/usr/local/bin' exists
> but is not a virtual environment

I have tensorflow and keras installed in my python 3.9. Here is my pip3 freeze output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Many installation issues are resolved by running the following in a **fresh R session** (you can restart R in Rstudio with Ctrl+Shift+F10) :

```
# install the development version of packages, in case the
# issue is already fixed but not on CRAN yet.
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github(sprintf("rstudio/%s", c("reticulate", "tensorflow", "keras")))
reticulate::miniconda_uninstall() # start with a blank slate
reticulate::install_miniconda()
keras::install_keras()
```

Test to see if installation was successful.

```
tensorflow::as_tensor("Hello World")
```

If the above snippet succeeded and you saw something like `tf.Tensor(b'Hello World', shape=(), dtype=string)`, then you've successfully installed Tensorflow!
If not, please file an issue at https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow/issues

Comment: Now I have this error:
Using virtual environment '~/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate' ...
sh: line 1: 21245 Abort trap: 6           '/Users/yuliai/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/bin/python' -c 'import sys; import pip; sys.stdout.write(pip.__version__)' 2>&1
Error: invalid version specification ‘’, ‘  ’

Comment: In addition: Warning messages:
1: In system2(python, c("-c", shQuote(command)), stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE) :
  running command ''/Users/yuliai/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/bin/python' -c 'import sys; import pip; sys.stdout.write(pip.__version__)' 2>&1' had status 134
2: In if (idx != -1) version <- substring(version, 1, idx - 1) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used