# cannot initialize keras/tensorflow/torch in R

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, torch

Following the simple introductory tutorial on https://keras.rstudio.com/articles/sequential_model.html

The script fails in the initialization of a sequential model:

```
library(keras)

>model <- keras_model_sequential() 
Error in py_initialize(config$python, config$libpython, config$pythonhome, : 
/Users/usr/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib - dlopen(/Users/usr/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib, 10): no suitable image found. Did find:
/Users/usr/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
/Users/usr/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

similarly, trying something simple with tensorflow yields the same error:

```
library(tensorflow)
> hello <- tf$constant("Hello")
Error in py_initialize(config$python, config$libpython, config$pythonhome,  : 
  /Users/usr/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib - dlopen(/Users/usr/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/usr/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Users/usr/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

I am using a Macbook Air M1, 2020 with Big Sur 11.1 and R:

```
> version
               _                           
platform       aarch64-apple-darwin20      
arch           aarch64                     
os             darwin20                    
system         aarch64, darwin20           
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          1.2                         
year           2021                        
month          11                          
day            01                          
svn rev        81115                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
nickname       Bird Hippie
```

I have tried to deleting my old R/RStudio from 2017, and reinstalling (shown in new version above). I have also attempted several methods of installing keras/tf shown below:

```
#attempt1
remove.packages("keras")
remove.packages("tensorflow")

#Restart R, and do:
install.packages("keras")
library(keras)
install_keras()
library(tensorflow)
> hello <- tf$constant("Hello")
Error in py_initialize(config$python, config$libpython, config$pythonhome,  : 
  /Users/usr/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib - dlopen(/Users/usr/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/usr/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Users/usr/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

```
#attempt2 from https://stackoverflow.com/a/58622375

remove.packages("keras")
remove.packages("tensorflow")

install.packages("keras")
install.packages("tensorflow")
library(keras)
library(tensorflow)
install_tensorflow()
install_keras(method = 'conda')
use_condaenv("r-reticulate", required = TRUE)
>hello <- tf$constant("Hello")
Error in py_initialize(config$python, config$libpython, config$pythonhome,  : 
  /Users/usr/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib - dlopen(/Users/usr/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/usr/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Users/usr/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

```
#attempt3 from https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow/blob/master/README.md

remove.packages("keras")
remove.packages("tensorflow")

devtools::install_github("rstudio/tensorflow")
library(tensorflow)
install_tensorflow()
> hello <- tf$constant("Hello")
Error in py_initialize(config$python, config$libpython, config$pythonhome,  : 
  /Users/usr/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib - dlopen(/Users/usr/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/usr/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Users/usr/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Note the same happens with torch:

```
install.packages("torch")
>library(torch)
Warning: Torch failed to start, restart your R session to try again. /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/library/torch/deps/liblantern.dylib - dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/library/torch/deps/liblantern.dylib, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/library/torch/deps/liblantern.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/library/torch/deps/liblantern.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

There is no error thrown while installing the packages in any above the above attempts. It is only when a library function is called. Please let me know if there is more information that would be helpful, for example:

```
% file $(which python)
/Users/usr/miniforge3/bin/python: Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64
```

Comment: Tensorflow on Apple Silicon is a developing story. Please take a look at the "Apple Silicon" section here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tensorflow/versions/2.7.0/topics/install_tensorflow

Comment: @t-kalinowski thanks for the answer. I've followed the directions outlined in the link provided but still getting the same error. The python's tf works but not R's. [Keras fails in both](https://github.com/mwidjaja1/DSOnMacARM). I've even tried adding `use_python("~/miniforge3/bin/python")` in the R Script but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the exact same issue, also on the new Apple M1 chip.

This worked for me:

1. Download miniforge
   Download and install Conda env (see link in Step 1 here: https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/

then in terminal

```
chmod +x ~/Downloads/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh
sh ~/Downloads/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh
```

2. Create and activate a new env, get tf from conda forge

```
conda create -n r-env python=3.8
conda activate r-env
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

3. Tell R where to look for python
   In your .REnviron file, add
   RETICULATE_PYTHON = "../miniforge3/envs/r-env/bin/python"
4. Restart R and tell it which env to use

```
if(!require("tensorflow")) { install.packages("tensorflow") }; library("tensorflow")
if(!require("keras")) { install.packages("keras") }; library("keras")
if(!require("reticulate")) { install.packages("reticulate") }; library("reticulate")
use_condaenv("r-env")
```

Then keras_model_sequential() was working fine.